# How do I convert str('2018-12-02T14:29:41.655+05:30') into date and time?

Tags: python

```py
date_object = datetime.strptime(one_bike.iloc[0,1], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+05:30').date()
```

Expected Results:

```
Date - '%Y-%m-%d'
Time - '%H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Does it work? Does it throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

From your title we can assume that `one_bike.iloc[0,1]` has `str('2018-12-02T14:29:41.655+05:30')` in it.

the reason your code doesn't work is that you're missing the milliseconds. you can add it by using `%S.%f`
so the code should look like

```
date_object = datetime.strptime(str('2018-12-02T14:29:41.655+05:30'), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+05:30').date()
```

Answer (score 0):

The strptime() class method takes two arguments:

- string (that be converted to datetime)
- format code

Considering the date string you are trying to convert is "2018-12-02T14:29:41.655+05:30".

This string is in the format of "Year-Month-DayThh:mm::ss.ms+05:30". So, the format string you have written is missing the microseconds directive (%f).

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = "2018-12-02T14:29:41.655+05:30"

date_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+05:30').date()

print ("date_object =", date_object)
print("type of date_object =", type(date_object))
```

[Python strptime()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime)
 has a very good reference document on this.